# How do I get Slam!, a 16-bit game, to run on Windows 98?

Tags: technical-issues, windows-98, slam

I have a few games that are 16-bit that I want to try on Windows 98, I know that 98 supports 16-bit programming, but the one game that I am using to test out keeps crashing. The error message I'm getting is:

> This program has preformed an illegal operation, if this problem persists, please contact the manufacturer.

Is there any way to fix or at least improve the quality on them?

(The game I am using is a freeware game called Slam!)

Comment: Rather than ask in a general sense, try to focus on your specific problem.  Do you have an error message?  What does it do when the game crashes?

Comment: ^What Frank said. without an error message or screenshot or something it's going to be pretty hard to help you solve the issue you're having

Comment: It just says, "This program has preformed an illegal operation, if this problem persists, please contact the manufacturer." (Sorry if I'm not good at questions, its my first time)

Comment: @Starvr344 - It's all good :). That error message is a pretty standard message on Windows 98 which could mean any number of things, but generally it comes down to how well the program was written. Do any of the other games come up with a similar message?

Comment: @robotnik I couldn't find any more 16-bit games that would go fit on my floppy, but I do know slam works fine on Windows 3.1, hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm sorry I'm not entirely sure, I've only a basic memory of Windows 98. :( Perhaps someone else might have more knowledge about this.

Comment: Why not just use [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) from within a modern OS

Comment: @NickT DOSBox is for MS-DOS games.

Comment: A) Windows 98 runs on MS-DOS, B) 16-bit is from the days of Windows 3.x (also MS-DOS), C) what does "...improve the quality on them?" even mean?

Comment: @NickT: DOSBox isn't really designed to run another OS inside it, especially not one that requires as much control as Win9x. [It's certainly possible](http://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=17324), but other VMs (e.g. VirtualBox) are probably a better bet (or Windows 3.1x, which is much easier to get running).

Comment: @Mich I just don't get where Win 98 fits in to playing a 16-bit game

Comment: @NickT: It fits in by being an OS capable of running 16-bit Windows games - presumably the only one the OP has (legitimate) access to (a modern 64-bit version of Windows can't do 16-bit) - and the problem might be an incompatibility in Win9x. Furthermore, DOSBox doesn't run Windows games on its own (it needs to run a compatible Windows version as an additional layer inside).

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem. I was unzipping it on another computer, *then* I put it on the floppy and on the 98. The newer unzipping program wasn't agreeing with the older computer.